# How to display which files that has "restore after commit" in the commit dialog?

Tags: tortoisesvn

It seems like the yellow (and vague but useful) icon for files that will be restored after commit (a feature that you activate for a file by right clicking in the commit dialog and pick "Restore after commit") has been removed. Instead the icon for the specific file type is still showing.

Is the feedback replaced with something else that lets me see which files that will restore after commit?

The feature "restore after commit" is really useful for partial commits in case I first mark one or more files for "restore after commit" and then in the interface "revert" lines that I do not want to be included in the commit and when the commit has been done, those changes are still present. (If I do another commit, they will show up again).

The restore after commit feature is still working, but it seems like the icon for the files in question is not any longer changed.

The visual feedback that a file will restore after commit is an extremely important control mechanism, because "restore after commit" is a riskful operation. I checked if any column reveals the information in textual form but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.
Already fixed in the trunk.
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/tortoisesvn/code
revision 27747
But not yet merged into the release build.
You can use nightly build, or rebuild release build with merged fix by yourself.

Comment: Should I close this then?

Comment: Thanks btw, I installed the nightly build and the icon is back :)

Comment: However, the precense of "ipv6" in the filename was confusing. How is that relevant, especially since there is no alternative download without "ipv6"...